# Can't install json 1.8.1

Tags: ruby, rvm, gem

I'm trying to install json gem using ruby 2.2.3 (I've tried with other oversions), and I always get the same error:

```
Fetching: json-1.8.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/michell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160425-25421-vzm9hx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:0:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h: In function ‘fbuffer_to_s’:
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:47: error: macro "rb_str_new" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                                           ^
../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:175:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 VALUE result = rb_str_new(FBUFFER_PAIR(fb));
                ^
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/michell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/michell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm getting this same error, trying to install all the stuff for Github Pages

Comment: I got the same error with ruby-2.3.0, so tried ruby-2.2.0 w/o any changes and it worked. When I see things like above "make'' error I guess I am dealing with a bug.

Answer (score 6):

I keep forgetting but this should work

```
bundle update
bundle install
```